# Android PHP Hello World

Tags: php, android

I am new to Android, but worked in PHP.   I heard we can invoke the PHP from Android, hence i thought its good idea to learn this and expecting more work in future.

Based on Stack Overflow,  i tried to write Hellow world from PHP to Android

```
<?php
    echo 'Hello World';
?>
```

And Its mentioned in Stack overflow the below code needs to be included.  I am referring the below

[How to retrieve a simple text like 'Hello world' from PHP to Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643465/how-to-retrieve-a-simple-text-like-hello-world-from-php-to-android).  Its mentioned the below code needs to be added in android manifest add.  But i am not getting that.

Please let me know where this code to be included in android. ( Note:  I can able to display hello world in android, but want to display the same from PHP).   If you have any example for Add, Delete, update a recrod from Android which invokes PHP also please share me.

```
String myString;
String url = "http://localhost/Androidphp/ind.php";
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpGet request;
try {
    request = new HttpGet(new URI(url));

    request.addHeader("User-Agent", "Android");


    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);

    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
        out.close();
        myString = out.toString();
    }
} catch (URISyntaxException e1) {

    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a simple google search for tutorials on using android with PHP? http://bit.ly/1b9nbKs

Comment: have you added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` permission in `AndroidMenifest.xml` ?

Comment: Sorry to break it to you, but Android and PHP have no connection, whatsoever. You can hit web page written in PHP from Android device, but it does not make it android specific

Comment: I tried Google Search and everything, but nothing working out.

Comment: `Its mentioned the below code needs to be added in android manifest add` You **didn't** write that code in the manifest, right??

Answer (score 0):

You have to add below permission in to your `(<YOUR PROJET/res/AndroidManifest.xml>)` file_

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>`
```

Just gone through [this tutorial - How to connect Android with PHP, MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/). you get a demo application code here which help you to understand it better.

I hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
                       HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                       HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/Androidphp/ind.php");
                       httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs1));
                       HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                       String the_string_response = convertResponseToString(response);
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response " + the_string_response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }catch(Exception e){
                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         System.out.println("Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                   } 

                    return null;
                }
```

use that method 
declare private variable

```
 InputStream inputStream;
```

public String convertResponseToString(HttpResponse response) throws IllegalStateException, IOException{

```
        String res = "";
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        int contentLength = (int) response.getEntity().getContentLength(); //getting content length…..
        System.out.println("content length "+contentLength);
  //      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "contentLength : " + contentLength, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (contentLength < 0){
        }
        else{
               byte[] data = new byte[512];
               int len = 0;
               try
               {
                   while (-1 != (len = inputStream.read(data)) )
                   {
                       buffer.append(new String(data, 0, len)); //converting to string and appending  to stringbuffer…..
                   }
               }
               catch (IOException e)
               {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               try
               {
                   inputStream.close(); // closing the stream…..
               }
               catch (IOException e)
               {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               res = buffer.toString();     // converting stringbuffer to string…..


        }
        return res;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to the game but for people who come across this post because the HTTPClient was depricated I was able to still talk to php using [volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley). I've used this to use php to enable myself to be able to interface from my android application to a mySQL database.